# Removing grey border around divs (on hover) in Windows 8 Metro style app

Tags: css, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm building a Windows 8 Metro style app and I'd like to style the tiles a little different than what's available out of the box. When the user hovers over a tile (div), a grey box appears around it. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Windows 8 app with grey border around a tile]

But there are no CSS styles associated with these grey borders in the code.

I tried overriding it anyway using the following code. But it didn't work.

```
div:hover {
  border: none;
}
```

**[Added in response to comments]** Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>App title</h1>
    <div id="categoriesTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div class="category">
            <a href="#" data-win-bind="innerText:title"></a>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div id="headerTemplate" 
            data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" 
           style="display: none">
        <div class="simpleHeaderItem">
            <h1 data-win-bind="innerText: title1"></h1>
        </div>
     </div>

  <div id="semanticZoomTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" 
       style="display: none">
        <div class="semanticZoomItem">
            <h1 class="semanticZoomItem-Text" 
                data-win-bind="innerText: title1">
             </h1>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div id="semanticZoomDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom"> 
          <div id="categoriesListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{itemTemplate:categoriesTemplate,
           groupHeaderTemplate: headerTemplate
           ,layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout} }">
        </div>  
      <div id="zoomedOutListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{itemTemplate: semanticZoomTemplate, 
                           selectionMode: 'none', 
                           tapBehavior: 'invoke', 
                           swipeBehavior: 'none' }">

        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS.

```
div.category:hover {
    width: 180px; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#f6f4d3;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:25px;
    color: #f6f4d3;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access the page with Firebug or similar? That could allow you to see the styles that are being applied.

Comment: It doesn't open up the browser. It runs on WinRT. So it adds itself to the start menu (the one with the tiles) and you run it from there. So no way to use Firebug. I don't know of a Firebug like tool to use to debug this either. VS Express isn't very helpful from this perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are rendering things in a list view.

Add the following style to your css...

```
#idOfYourListView .win-container:hover {
    background-color: red; 
    outline: orange solid 5px;
}
```

If you are not using a ListView, please post the HTML you are using to create the screen shot.

Comment: I've updated the question and added the HTML & the corresponding CSS code. While "outline" property looked promising, it didn't remove the border even after I set it to none, unfortunately.

Comment: Jeff is right, only you can't set it to none, you have to use transparent. See my answer.

Comment: Actually, this worked on the 2nd try (after I made another minor change that was initially overriding this style). Thanks for your help.

@Jeremy, setting it to "none" worked. However, "transparent" did not show up in intellisense for the the "outline" attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Jeff was right about the style selector. You don't need the background-color property, though. The outline: transparent works on its own. I just tried it.

```
#myList .win-container:hover {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover styling may likely be associated with a link and possibly a class rather than div for that element.

As KRyan suggested, use a debugger to find out which element you are targeting, else try to change some of the **a** or other **hover** elements in the CSS file, trial and error until you find the right one.

Comment: Links don't have any hover style set either. And I used Blend to confirm that the hover over is indeed happening on the div and not on the link it contains.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a WinRT app that uses HTML/CSS/JS, you just F5 your app and while it's running, you go to the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio. If you don't see it as a tab, then go to Debug | Windows | DOM Explorer (if you haven't seen the JavaScript Console, you should look at that too!). Now you can hit the Select Element button (near the top of the DOM Explorer) and then select an element in the app.

Comment: the dom only shows elements with which the user has interacted (ex: if I clicked on button X, then yes, it highlights the properties added to that button), but in case of hovering over an element, somehow that is not caught and nothing is highlighted. In theory, yes, you are correct, that's how it should work. But it doesn't. :(

Comment: What do you mean by highlighted?

Comment: I mean actually highlight the piece of code that's being changed/added, on the left side. But that's because of the stacking of the elements. When dealing with such cases I tend to visualize them as layers (since I'm mainly a designer and photoshop is like my third arm), and the layer I was interested in, was below the layer that was receiving the mouse over (through z-indexing), which caused the debugger to not catch the js call of adding properties to the element. That's my best guess. I've seen it happen to regular html-css as well, so no biggie. best advice in this case is:read the MS docu